# SVG textpath rendering breaks words up badly on a textpath with sharp corners

Tags: svg

(nb branched from [SVG textpath text layout on complex, changing paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893266/svg-textpath-text-layout-on-complex-changing-paths) as the first problem was solved and I can't manage two separate answers)

I am not sure the problem I have is solvable using the current SVG standard but I thought I would ask here anyway if anyone knows an answer

I have a constantly changing svg path (vertices defined by forming a hull around nodes made in d3, force driven so the nodes constantly move and the bounding hull moves to accomodate the nodes)

Because I can't predict the vertices nor do I know what the text will be (as it depends on the grouping of the nodes in that situation, which changes) all i can do is blindly apply text on a textpath to the path. The problem is sometimes the text does not display nicely. and I get broken up text glyphs - when a corner forms, text has a tendency to split up. I don't think my use of dy to push the text outside the boundary helps (the path is actually tight to the nodes and I apply a 40 stroke-width to give some padding: the dy pushed the text outside that stroke)

For example (image):

[image]

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?  My thought is that is the stroke-width wasn't there it would be splitting around a sharp point and it kind of makes sense.  With the stroke width it just doesn't take into account of the effective curve.

Can I influence the rendering to stop this happening?

--Chris

svg code for reference:

```
<g id="hull_elements"><path class="boundary" id="Secure" d="M30.716331539726912,88.02778447495649L66.8405337274694,100.01086904278971L251.78816229874747,53.214214251587265L277.8704519199028,25.642491075146587Z" style="fill: #b0c4de; stroke: #b0c4de; stroke-width: 40px; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
<path class="boundary" id="DMZ" d="M177.8575710153683,149.56053657599713L251.04637461899244,245.55658992744486L277.76418020025847,271.7261370009561L159.53295211932644,118.0340968521715Z" style="fill: #b0c4de; stroke: #b0c4de; stroke-width: 40px; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
</g>
<g id="hull_text">
<text dy="30"><textPath startOffset="0" text-anchor="start" method="align" spacing="auto" xlink:href="#Secure">Secure</textPath></text>
<text dy="30"><textPath startOffset="0" text-anchor="start" method="align" spacing="auto" xlink:href="#DMZ">DMZ</textPath></text>
</g>
```

jsfiddle to play with that shows this (move the nodes to see the issues) http://jsfiddle.net/zuzzy/GC2C2/

Comment: Maybe you could use bezier curves or elliptical arcs to avoid sharp path corners. You'd have to calculate the correct curve or arc parameters though.

Comment: As my path is generated from a strict hull around nodes by d3 I suspect I'm stuck there, unless some sort of transform could be run over a d3 generated path to generate a secondary path that has no sharp angles, without compromising performance given the hull/path changes 10s of times a second... I will however tweet Mike Bostock and see if he knows whether you can pad a hull in some way (such as rander nodes much larger) to avoid the issue