# textPath labels on convex hulls

Tags: d3.js, svg, geometry, label

I'm trying to make labels work on convex hulls. As a starting point I used this excellent tutorial (http://civicvision.de/blog/en/2015/06/23/convex-polygon-offset.html).
Unfortunately, the labels are always positioned differently on the hull. Sometimes it is on the top center but in other cases it is on the right bottom part of the hull.
Then, it is even impossible to surround the hull with text such that the whole outer line is used. The basic problem can be also observed in the linked tutorial (Group 1 is positioned vertically)

I think, it has something to do how the convex hull is constructed. 
Do I have to sort the points of the hull path in some way to make sure that the associated text path always starts in the upper left part of the hull?

[image: label positions vary]

I would be really grateful if somebody could help me out with this problem!

Best Regards
Jan

Comment: I hacked an example to show that labels are not always shown in the upper center part of the hulls (http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/4916c33065750dae1477887d1446677b).
Is there a way to always show these labels in a desired position relative to the hull?

Comment: my question is actually based on the problem expressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893266/svg-textpath-text-layout-on-complex-changing-paths